# TWAIN Browser Plugin

Tags: plugins, twain

Does anyone know of a good TWAIN browser plugin to scan images and send to a web application? If it includes features such as deskew it would be even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google found several commercial ones and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Web_Twain.aspx) which is free.

I've done some very simple things with it and found it to actually work with my Fujitsu fi-5120 scanners.

Comment: This solution requires a local permission to run executable from the JS code on a web page. Most environments won't allow this since it is not safe.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid special permission on the client, either granted by the user or by system administrator, because scanning requires access to the local system that is not available in HTML, javascript or java.  Native code must be run - ActiveX, plugin, exe, setup, signed applet - any of which requires special permission at some level.

Answer (score 2):

And... Atalasoft (now a subsidiary of Kofax) has a web scanning toolkit:

[Atalasoft WingScan product page](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/wingscan)

Disclaimer: I am an employee and one of the co-authors of the product.

The scanning component is based on the EZTwain library, and it definitely includes deskew ;-)

You can optionally license and use embedded VRS technology, which I have to say is impressively good at cleaning up scans.

Comment: VRS, from my friend Dean Hough. Impressive indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use https://www.docapi.net for integration twain capability to my web apps, it based on Dynamsoft.